# jQuery DataTables Autosize height

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, zurb-foundation

I have DataTable in the div. I need that design stay responsive. That means that when I resize window, all controlling elements must stay intact, but the height of data area (rows only) has to adjust.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us some code you tried today??